# How to filter an implode result by a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to implode data MySQL database.

**I have an implode result like this :**

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

**And what I want is like this (I want filter number 3 from the result) :**

```
1,2,4,5
```

What I have done :

```
$result = [];

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM user") or die (mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

$result[] = $row['id'];

$implode = implode(",", $result);

echo $implode;
```

Is there any way to filter that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the 'if' construct**

> *Find this code:*
>
> ```
> $result[] = $row['id'];
> ```

if you need to compare a variable with a value, instead of doing:

> *Change this line with:*
>
> ```
> if($row['id'] != '3'){
> $result[] = $row['id'];
> }
> ```